# CUDAToolkit_INCLUDE_DIR has no effect

Tags: cmake, cuda

`CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(ProjectName)
find_package(CUDAToolkit)
```

```bash
$ cmake .. 
-- Unable to find cuda_runtime.h in "/usr/share/cuda/include" for CUDAToolkit_INCLUDE_DIR.
-- Unable to find cudart library.
-- Could NOT find CUDAToolkit (missing: CUDA_CUDART) (found version "12.2.91")
-- Configuring done (0.0s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: /home/Geremia/Downloads
```

When I specify the include directory containing `cuda_runtime.h` on my build of CUDA, it doesn't search that directory:

```bash
$ cmake .. -DCUDAToolkit_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/share/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include
-- Unable to find cuda_runtime.h in "/usr/share/cuda/include" for CUDAToolkit_INCLUDE_DIR.
-- Unable to find cudart library.
-- Could NOT find CUDAToolkit (missing: CUDA_CUDART) (found version "12.2.91")
-- Configuring done (0.0s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: /home/Geremia/Downloads
```

The same holds for `CUDAToolkit_ROOT`, too; it has no effect.

Comment: Documentation for [FindCUDAToolkit](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindCUDAToolkit.html) does not describe `CUDAToolkit_INCLUDE_DIR` as variable which could affect on searching. Setting `CUDAToolkit_ROOT` variable should work.. but according to the code of [FindCUDAToolkit.cmake](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindCUDAToolkit.cmake), it searches in the `targets` subdirectory only when **cross-compiling**. Are you cross-compiling your project?

Comment: @Tsyvarev Nothing changes when I specify `CUDAToolkit_ROOT`, either.

Answer (score -1):

This was due to an improper installation of CUDA.